# Must $a,b>1$ for $\int_1^a\frac 1tdt+\int_1^b\frac1tdt=\int_1^{ab}\frac1tdt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

In Spivak's *Calculus* (4th edition), Chapter 13, problem 15, the author asks to prove:

> For $a,b>1$ prove that:
>   $$\int_1^a\frac 1tdt+\int_1^b\frac1tdt=\int_1^{ab}\frac1tdt$$ 
>   The result is used in some problems in the following chapter, but I can't find in it's proof why $a,b$ must greater than 1, and the problem 14-28(c)(shown in the end) do use it regardless $a,b$'s range.

Here's the proof in answer book:

> Notice that
>   $$
> \frac1b\cdot \inf\{ \frac1t:t_{i-1}\leq t\leq t_i \}=\inf\{\frac1t:bt_{i-1}\leq x\leq bt_i \}
> $$
>   Denoting the first $\inf$ by $m_i$ and the second by $m_i^\prime$, we have
>   \begin{aligned}
> L(f,P\prime)
> &=\sum_{i=1}^nm_i^\prime(bt_i-bt_{i-1})\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^nbm_i^\prime(t_i-t_{i-1})\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^nm_i(t_i-t_{i-1})\\
> &=L(f,P).
> \end{aligned}
>   So
>   $$
> \int_b^{ab}\frac1tdt=\sup\{L(f,P\prime)\}=\sup\{L(f,P)\}=\int_1^a\frac1tdt.
> $$

Finally, in Chapter 14 problem 28-c, in the answer book, he just say:

> Problem 13-15 implies that
>   $$\int_{1/2}^1\frac1xdx+...+\int_{1/2}^1\frac1xdx=\int_{1/2^n}^1\frac1xdx$$

even reverse$\int_{1/2}^1$ to $-\int_1^{1/2}$, still doesn't make sense if $a,b$ can not be less than $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly, in chapter 13, Spivak only defined $\int_a^b f$ for $a < b$. So the upper limit is greater than the lower limit. It is only in chapter 14 that he defines the integral $\int_a^bf$ when $b\leq a$. I think this is why he imposes the condition $a,b > 1$ in your question. After defining things appropriately, it should be pretty easy to deduce the equality even when $a,b \leq 1$.

---

Edit:

I just checked my copy of Spivak (3rd Edition). He actually defines $\int_a^b$ for $b \leq a$ in chapter 13, right after Theorem 13-4.

In the $3$rd edition, the question reads

> Prove that
>   \begin{align}
> \int_1^a \dfrac{1}{t} \, dt + \int_1^b \dfrac{1}{t} \, dt = \int_1^{ab} \dfrac{1}{t} \, dt
> \end{align}
>   Hint:   ......

So, he actually doesn't impose any restriction on $a,b$ (the only restriction we should impose is $a,b > 0$). So, actually, you might have to do some case work. If in your edition he says $a,b > 1$, then that's fine, but eventually he'll make use of this property for all $a,b > 0$, so you should see how to extend to proof to all cases.

---

Additional Remark:

Spivak proves this equality using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in Theorem 18-1, for all $a,b > 0$. Even though it is more work, you should still try to see how to extend the "proof by partitions" to all cases.

Comment: I guess he only assume it so that $ab>b$.
To make the question easier?

Answer (score 3):

For $a,b\gt1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^a\frac1t\mathrm{d}t+\int_1^b\frac1t\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_1^a\frac1t\mathrm{d}t+\int_a^{ab}\frac1{t/a}\mathrm{d}t/a\tag1\\
&=\int_1^a\frac1t\mathrm{d}t+\int_a^{ab}\frac1t\mathrm{d}t\tag2\\
&=\int_1^{ab}\frac1t\mathrm{d}t\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $t\mapsto t/a$ in the right integral
$(2)$: cancel factors
$(3)$: addition of integrals with adjacent intervals

---

We can do the same thing for $0\lt a,b\lt1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^1\frac1t\mathrm{d}t+\int_b^1\frac1t\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_{ab}^b\frac1{t/b}\mathrm{d}t/b+\int_b^1\frac1t\mathrm{d}t\tag4\\
&=\int_{ab}^b\frac1t\mathrm{d}t+\int_b^1\frac1t\mathrm{d}t\tag5\\
&=\int_{ab}^1\frac1t\mathrm{d}t\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: substitute $t\mapsto t/b$ in the right integral
$(5)$: cancel factors
$(6)$: addition of integrals with adjacent intervals

Comment: Thank you for your help, your way to say (1) makes me to think as lower sum and upper sum are viewed as rectangles, multiply the height equals to multiply the width, so for any integrable functions we should have $\int_a^bf\cdot c=\int_{ac}^{bc}f$, is it true?

Comment: @user401653: that is not true. In $(1)$, each instance of $t$ is replaced by $t/a$. I have added a step for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fact $\ln ab=\ln a+\ln b$.  This is true for any $a,b\gt0$.

Comment: You did not even read what was his question.